# Dell T330 Ubuntu 14.04 Server Installation

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, dell

Does anyone know how to install Ubuntu Server on the Dell Poweredge T330? There's already a LifeCycle Controller built into the BIOS of the server which offers many OS choices but no Ubuntu.It Looks like this:

[image]

The instruction manual for the server does not explain manual installation at all and Dell is charging tons of money for support, so the way I'm planning to do this is the way I did it for a PC, which is to format a USB, mount the Ubuntu Server .iso file onto the stick, plugin the stick into the server, restart and boot from USB in the server. The version I'm planning to use is the i386 32-bit, since here it states that this version compatible with Intel, and the server's chipset is Intel C236:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-server-i386.iso

Answer (score 0):

Managed to complete installation by mounting the iso onto a CD-R on a separate computer and loading the CD directly into the server during the OS deployment. Seems that the T330 Lifecycle Controller is finicky about bootable USBs!